# javascript generated content in .Net windows forms application?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

i want to load some content from an "HTML" page in to a windows forms application
the problem is that the content on the HTML page will be generated by javascript so i am confused with what should i do, so if you have a solution then please tell me.
Otherwise if someone can tell me about how can i embed IE into windows forms application then load that page into it AND THEN load the content generated by javascript into my form application then it will also work.

I am using .Net 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `WebBrowser` control onto the form and set its `Url` property.

Comment: When you run the application, it will contain embedded IE on your form with the web page you set in the Url property. Do you need anything else?

Comment: i had understand that part my most important concern and the whole reason to use the web browser control is to select the content generated by javascript, i know i can select the content using WebBrowser.DocumentText property but will it let me access the js generated content?

Comment: It should. Just try to do it.